# Calling perl module from current directory

Tags: perl, perl-module

I need to test a perl script in a remote server. I tried running it but i got the error

```
Can't locate Date/Manip.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .
```

So I downloaded the DateManip.pm file and tried to copy it in one of the locations mentioned. But I don't have permission to copy the file in any of these places. Is there a way I can have this *.pm file in my own directory and call it from there or do I HAVE to put it in one of those locations?

Comment: Related useful article: [How to change @INC to find Perl modules in non-standard locations](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to do this is install DateManip.pm obviously, however if you cannot for some reason do that, then you can copy the module to any directory you have write permissions to and modify the perl script to include the following:

```
 use FindBin qw($Bin);
 use lib "$Bin/<relative_path_to_module>";
```

`<relative_path_to_module>` is the relative path to the directory where DateManip.pm is located.  So if the relative path to the module is ../lib, you would have

```
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/../lib";
```

Comment: is got the following error - "$BIN" is not exported by the FindBin module.

Comment: case matters...it should be $Bin not $BIN

Answer (score 3):

By default Perl will also look in the current directory (where it is being run) for a module.  So the following will work:

```
./your_program.pl     <= "use DateManip"
./DateManip.pm
```

If the module was called Date::Manip then the structure would need to be like this:

```
./your_program.pl     <= "use Date::Manip"
./Date/
./Date/Manip.pm
```

Comment: Valid on Perl 5.22.1? I have my module on current directory and everything works fine... but B::Lint complain "Can't locate Mymodule.pm in @INC".

Comment: @PabloBianchi - Yes valid on Perl 5.22.   But no longer valid (by default) from Perl 5.26 - http://perldoc.perl.org/perldelta.html#Removal-of-the-current-directory-(%22.%22)-from-%40INC

Comment: is there a workaround in Perl 5.26 and later?

Comment: @draegtun's link now shows a newer changelog instead of the intended one. Permalink to the 5.26.0 changelog: https://perldoc.perl.org/5.26.0/perldelta#Removal-of-the-current-directory-%28%22.%22%29-from-%40INC